# Allocating memory for a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to reserve space for a vector of vectors, but it doesn't work and throws the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Every time I use a large enough number. A minimal version of what I have is below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

  int base;
  cout << "Enter Base: ";
  cin >> base;

  int dimension;
  cout << "Enter Dimension: ";
  cin >> dimension;

  int perms = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
    perms *= base;
  } // This gets the number of permutations with repetition

  int length;
  cout << "Enter Length: ";
  cin >> length;

  float structSize = 1.0;

  for(float i=0.0; i<length; i++){
    structSize *= perms-i;
    structSize /= (i+1.0);
  } // This gets the number of combinations

  vector< vector< vector<double> > > allStructs;
  allStructs.reserve(structSize); 

  return 0;
}
```

It should work for large structSizes, but fails at base=3, dimension=4, length=6 which makes structSize=324,540,216. Is it possible for this to work?

Comment: Yes it is possible - add more memory to your PC

Comment: Did you do the math on how much memory this would require?

Comment: Do you really to store each results ? can't you just iterate over the result instead ?

Comment: I wonder if you are actually calculating the correct structSize. You only need to calculate how many `vector<vector<double>>` you actually want to reserve. That should be a relatively small number. I have the impression you are calculating the overall number of doubles you need. But even that already amounts to more than 2GB, which could be too much on a 32 bit machine, and still a lot on a 64 bit one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to think about your memory use.

> It should work for large structSizes, but fails at base=3, dimension=4, length=6 which makes structSize=324,540,216. Is it possible for this to work?

So what you're doing, at an abstract level, is allocating a data structure that contains `324,540,216` instances of a `vector<vector<double>>` object.

Here's what we know about `vector` objects:

- Its size must be at least 16 bytes; it needs to store a pointer, which in a 64-bit architecture, is probably 8 bytes, and it needs to store a size, which will probably also be 8 bytes.
- Its size is probably going to be significantly bigger, since the moment you instantiate the last `vector<double>` object, it's going to consume another [at-least-] 16 bytes each time you create one.

So just on the face of it, your `allStructs.reserve(structSize)` call is allocating 5 Gigabytes. It's probably allocating more than that, since the size of a vector's metadata could very well be larger than 16 bytes.

Comment: Technically, there's no limit on the size of a vector, if all it stores is an index into a vector array elsewhere. Even on the more realistic side, I saw an implementation of `std::string` once where the internal pointer pointed at the data, and stored the size and capacity at mData[-4] and mData[-8], which meant that `printf("%s", myStdString)` would actually work.

Comment: @MooingDuck Fair point, although it would still cause memory allocation issues the moment the user tried to actually store and work with values in each of those indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your StructSize as `double StructSize = 1.0;` then it should "*logically*" work.

However, `reserve()` might not work due to possible memory limitations on your PC.